# Function of almost independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

This question is a bit vague because I am not sure how to formalise it properly.

Let $f\colon \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ be a well behaved (let's say smooth and bounded) function of two variables. Let $X,Y,Y'$ be random variables distributed as $X \sim d_1$ and $Y,Y'\sim d_2$, where $d_1,d_2$ are well behaved distributions on $\mathbb R$ (let's say continuous density, existing moments of all orders). We also assume that $X$ is independent from $Y$ and *almost independent* from $Y'$. I am not sure how to formalise almost independent in this context, I could imagine a condition like
$$\text{Cov}(g(X),h(Y'))\le \epsilon \|g' \|_\infty \|h' \|_\infty $$ 
for all differentiable functions $g,h$, where $\epsilon>0$ is some small constant.

The question now is what can be said about 
$$\left\lvert\mathbf E f(X,Y)-\mathbf E f(X,Y')\right\rvert $$
maybe in terms of $\epsilon$?

Intuitively this difference should be small as $Y'$ is almost independent of $X$ and $Y$ could be thought as an independent copy of $Y'$.