# Can random variables be 'almost' independent (similar to almost surely, almost everywhere, etc)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

Some concepts of almost:

1. Almost everywhere / almost surely - holds true except for a set of measure zero
2. 'Liminf' in probability - will hold true eventually i.e. holds true except for finitely many events.

(You know Gasai what I mean. Please don't let me elaborate.)

2 random variables $X$ and $Y$ in the same probability space are independent if and only if

$$E[f(X)g(Y)] = E[f(X)]E[g(Y)] \tag{A}$$

(I guess we're talking about integrable random variables? Or need not integrable?) for all $f,g$ 'well-behaved' (for advanced probability: 'Borel-measurable and then bounded or integrable or whatever').

**Question:** Is there like a thing where $(A)$ holds for all but finitely/countably many $f,g$ or something?

Or is there some rule that if (A) holds for all except possibly for 1 $f,g$, then (A) also holds for $f,g$? Well...ummm...if (A) holds for $2f,2g$, then I guess $(A)$ holds for $f,g$. What about all scalar multiples of $f,g$? But this is uncountably many of course.

Other posts I've found that attempt to quantify almost independence:

1. [Almost independent random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2719015/almost-independent-random-variables)
2. [Function of almost independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269982/function-of-almost-independent-random-variables)
3. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67328/relations-between-probabilities-of-almost-independent-random-variables

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_dependent_random_variables

Comment: @Alborz dumb it down for me please. Are the $\mathscr F$'s supposed to be the $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: I actually don't know anything about weakly dependent random variables, I just remember coming across the term in my textbook. Sorry!

Comment: @Alborz ok thanks no need to apologise.

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer:

I think we can't have all but countably many functions because there are uncountably many scalar multiples of any function.

Let's say we have all except possibly for $\{f_n,g_m\}_{n,m=1}^{\infty}$. Pick your favourite positive integers $a,b$. Then there must exist some non-zero scalars $s,t$ s.t. $sf_a,tg_b \notin \{f_n,g_m\}_{n,m=1}^{\infty}$. Then $(A)$ holds for $sf_a,tg_b$ and then for $f_a,g_b$.